# Typo3 extbase - HMENU with multiple records

Tags: typo3, typoscript, records

I have a products extension with a "Details" view.
"Product" records are kept in a folder with ID 5.
When I am on a product I want to have a menu with links to all the products from that folder.
I this possible in Typoscript?

Thank you.

Comment: I browsed through the docs and couldn't find a starting point, so I ended up making a plugin for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything using TypoScript :-).

```
lib.productList = CONTENT
lib.productList {
  table = tx_myext_domain_model_product
  select {
    # sorting criterion
    orderBy = tstamp DESC
    # PID list
    pidInList = 46,47
    # Maybe restrict the number of results
    max = 20
  }
  # Each result must be rendered like this
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    1 = TEXT
    # Each field from your table can be used
    1.field = title
    1.wrap = <h1>|</h1>

    2 = TEXT
    2.field = description
    # If one field contains rich text, you can apply RTE parsing to it
    2.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
  }

}
```

Now you can use the cObject ViewHelper to display your list in the Fluid template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.productList"></f:cObject>
```